# how to fit the background image to the containing anchor element?

Tags: css

I'm trying to design a link with an image background, question is if the image is too large, how do i fit it to the width and height of the anchor using css?

```
<a href="#"></a>
<style>
 a
 {  
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image: url('/Scripts/images/downarrow_blue.png');
    }
</style>
```

tia,
Lina

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Background images in CSS 2.1 cannot be resized, although CSS 3 supports the [`background-size`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) property it's not widely implemented.

```
background-size: 10px 10px;
```

The obvious alternative is to just use an `<img>` tag:

```
<a href="#"><img src="mybg.png" alt="" style="width:10px; height:10px" /></a>
```

But you probably have a reason for not doing it that way anyway, right?

Other alternatives might be

- Resize the `<a>` element to the size of the image instead.
- Resize the image locally and upload it under a different filename.
- Use a server-side preprocessor such as PHP or ASP to deliver the image in the size you want.

Comment: yes i actually have a reason for using it as a background, as i have to change the picture on hover, thank you :)

Comment: For me background-size was the solution but I also had to use the width and height attribute.

Comment: If you don't know the size of the image (or whatever other element you are applying this to) the code "background-size: 100% 100%;" should work.